# Web Service error - The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action '' is incorrect or because

Tags: wcf, security, token

> the message contains an invalid expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings

The problem is, the client and the server times are a few seconds off. The web services all work fine, unless the call is made in between the few seconds that the client/server are off. So, if the call is made, and the client time is 6:00:58, and the server time is 6:01:01, the error above occurs.

I have added code to catch the exception, and try the call again, but keep getting this message.

I have synced the times on client/server, but they eventually get out of sync be a few seconds.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is part of the web config that matters (everything between client/server is same) :

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior" name="WebService.TestService">
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Service" 
        contract="WebService.ITestService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="./WebService/TestService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>    

</services>
<bindings>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Service" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="900000" maxStringContentLength="900000" maxArrayLength="900000" maxBytesPerRead="900000" maxNameTableCharCount="900000" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>

</bindings>   

 <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a custom binding that mimics `wsHttpBinding` that will let you increase the `maxClockSkew` on the security settings to be outside the error range. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx). Too bad you can't do it directly on the existing `wsHttpBinding`.